# Webpack: How to change the global variable name for export modules?

Tags: javascript, webpack

**Example:**

1. Project **A** in which the lodash library is in. _.VERSION: 4.17.5
2. Project **B** in which I execute  webpack assembly in which lodash is added. _.VERSION: 3.10.1
   And I create the file Time.Core.js

**webpack.config.js**

```
   var getWebpackConfig = function() {
        return {
            context: __dirname + "/src/scripts",
            entry: {
                Core: "./Core",
                Editor: "./Editor",
            },
            devtool: "source-map",
            externals: [
                {
                    'jquery': {
                        root: '$',
                        commonjs: 'jquery',
                        commonjs2: 'jquery',
                        amd: 'jquery'
                    }
                }
            ],
            output: {
                path: path.join(__dirname, "dist/scripts"),
                filename: "Time.[name].js",
                libraryTarget: "umd",
                library: ["Time", "[name]"]
            },
            module: {
                loaders: [
                    {
                        test: /\.js$/,
                        exclude: [/node_modules/, /dist/],
                        loader: 'babel',
                        query: {
                            presets: ['es2015']
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.tpl.html$/,
                        loader: 'mustache'
                    }
                ],
            },
            plugins: [
            ]
        };
    };
```

After including Time.Core.js in project **A**, the global variable for lodash is replaced and the version becomes 3.10.1

**Question:** how to change a variable during assembly for some modules so that when including to project A, I can access it without using noConflict ()?

- _.VERSION: 4.17.5
- _namespace.VERSION: 3.10.1

Thank you.